# React-bootstrap call method of external component

Tags: forms, modal-dialog, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap to launch a modal form.

To do that I created a modal component `PopupForm`, a form component `ProductForm`, a product component, in the product component I call

```
<ModalTrigger 
    modal={<PopupForm form={<ProductForm ref="pform" data={this.props.prod_data} />}/>}>
       <Button bsStyle='primary' bsSize='small' style={{marginRight:'5px'}} >
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" />
       </Button>
</ModalTrigger>
```

`PopupForm`:

```
var PopupForm = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <Modal {...this.props} bsStyle='primary' 
                   style={{width:200}} title='Edition' animation={false}>
            <div className='modal-body'>
                {this.props.form}
            </div>
            <div className='modal-footer'>
              <Button onClick={this.props.form.submit()}>Editer</Button>
              <Button onClick={this.props.onRequestHide}>Close</Button>
            </div>
          </Modal>
        )
    }
});
```

On this `onClick` Editer, I would like to call the method `submit` of the `ProductForm` component, the `ProductForm` component is send to `PopupForm` in the prop form, I display it like this `{this.props.form}`, but I can't call the method `{this.props.form.submit()}`
Actually I'd like to use the modal button to trigger ProductForm method if it's not possible I will use a submit button inside the ProductForm.

Here is my `ProductForm`:

```
var ProductForm = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.props.submit = this.submit;
    },


    getInitialState: function () {
        return {canSubmit: false};
     },

    enableButton: function () {
      this.setState({
        canSubmit: true
      });
    },
    disableButton: function () {
      this.setState({
        canSubmit: false
      });
    },
    submit: function (model) {
      alert('ok');
    },
    render: function () {
      return (

            <Formsy.Form className="" name="test" onValidSubmit={this.submit} onValid={this.enableButton} onInvalid={this.disableButton}>


              <CsInput value={this.props.data.name} 
                label="Nom" id="product_name" 
                name={this.props.data.name}
                validations={{matchRegexp: /^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,30}$/}} 
                validationError={validations_errors[1]} required/>



              {/*<button type="submit" disabled={!this.state.canSubmit}>Submit</button>*/}


            </Formsy.Form>
      );
    }
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

if you have nested components you can call the other one's function like so:

**Child:**

```
var Component1 = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div><button onClick={this.props.callback}>click me</button></div>
        )
    }
})
```

**Parent:**

```
var Component2 = React.createClass({
    doSomethingInParent: function() {
        console.log('I called from component 2');
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div><component1 callback={this.doSomethingInParent} /></div>
        )
    }
})
```

Same goes in your case. It wasn't very clear in your code so I couldn't help you with the code Itself. If you get messy with this please post your entire code In a Hierarchically way so It'll be more readable.

Comment: This is the 'react way' of doing it. Anything which you need which is shared by multiple components (actions or data) should come from a common parent